# React native app crashes on loading 200+ data in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have list of data which comes with infinite scroll in flatlist. Number of the posts is 200+. When I am running the app on low end devices it is crashing.

I tried adding props removeClippedSubviews to true but this doesn't help a lot.

Also I checked memory used by app in the background. It keeps on increasing.
How to manage this memory?

```
          <FlatList
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
            initialNumToRender={5}
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            bounces={false}
            onRefresh={()=>this.refreshAllTweets()}
            data={tweets}
            ref={(c) => {this.flatList = c;}}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            onEndReached={()=>this.endReached()}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TweetItem reloadComponent={()=>this.reload()} name={this.state.name}  onPress={()=>this.goToDetail(item.id)} onImagePress={()=>this.toggleModal(item.id)} onCommentPress={()=>this.showComments(item.id)} tweet={item}/>}
            />
```

This is how my flatlist code looks like

Comment: check if phone is old, then add a button (show more) to limit the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid anonymous function which is likely the root cause of the crash problem, it will re-create each time your item is rendered. **Extract all anonymous functions**.

Also, memoize event handler will also help to minimize unnecessary re-render which bloated your memory. You can get the use of lodash library to achieve this.

```
yarn add lodash
```

Here is the performant way to render FlatList.

```
import { memoize, curry } from "lodash/fp";

class YourComponent {
  assignRef = (c) => {
    this.flatList = c;
  }

  onTweetPress = memoize(curry((id, _ev) => {
    this.goToDetail(item.id)
  }));

  onImagePress = memoize(curry((id, _ev) => {
    this.toggleModal(id)
  }));

  onImagePress = memoize(curry((id, _ev) => {
    this.toggleModal(id)
  }));

  onCommentPress = memoize(curry((id, _ev) => {
    this.showComments(id)
  }));

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TweetItem
      reloadComponent={this.reload}
      name={this.state.name}
      onPress={this.onTweetPress(item.id)}
      onImagePress={this.onImagePress(item.id)}
      onCommentPress={this.onCommentPress(item.id)}
      tweet={item}
    />
  )

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => (index.toString())

  render() {
      return (
      <FlatList
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        refreshing={this.state.refresh}
        bounces={false}
        onRefresh={this.refreshAllTweets}
        data={tweets}
        ref={this.assignRef}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        onEndReached={this.endReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```